# jQuery swap div order

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of divs that I want to be able to reorder by the use of buttons. These buttons would be called "move up" and "move down".

I want to hide the "move up" button on the first div and the "move down" button on the last div (or hide both if there is only one div). There can be no div, 1, 2, or many within the container.

The HTML would look something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div0">
        <button class="btn-move-up">Move up</button>
        <button class="btn-move-down">Move down</button>
    </div>
    <div id="div1">
        <button class="btn-move-up">Move up</button>
        <button class="btn-move-down">Move down</button>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <button class="btn-move-up">Move up</button>
        <button class="btn-move-down">Move down</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('button').click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).closest('div');
        if ($(this).hasClass('btn-move-up')) {
            parent.insertBefore(parent.prev('div'));
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('btn-move-down')) {
            parent.insertAfter(parent.next('div'));
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/maUGM/1/).

Edited to add in the omitted functionality (hiding the relevant buttons):

```
function firstAndLast(container) {
    if (!container) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        container.find('button:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
        container.find('button.btn-move-up:first').prop('disabled', true);
        container.find('button.btn-move-down:last').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}

firstAndLast($('#container'));

$('button').click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).closest('div'),
            grandparent = $(this).closest('#container');
        if ($(this).hasClass('btn-move-up')) {
            parent.insertBefore(parent.prev('div'));
            firstAndLast(grandparent)
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('btn-move-down')) {
            parent.insertAfter(parent.next('div'));
            firstAndLast(grandparent)
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/maUGM/2/).

Edited with regards to the revelation that `button` elements are not, in fact, being used. Instead, we're now using `a` elements:

```
function firstAndLast(container) {
    if (!container) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        container.find('a.disabled').removeClass('disabled')
        container.find('a.btn-move-up:first').addClass('disabled');
        container.find('a.btn-move-down:last').addClass('disabled');
    }
}

firstAndLast($('#container'));

$('a').click(
    function(e) {
        var that = $(this);
        if (!that.hasClass('disabled')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var parent = $(this).closest('div'),
                grandparent = $(this).closest('#container');
            if ($(this).hasClass('btn-move-up')) {
                parent.insertBefore(parent.prev('div'));
                firstAndLast(grandparent)
            }
            else if ($(this).hasClass('btn-move-down')) {
                parent.insertAfter(parent.next('div'));
                firstAndLast(grandparent)
            }
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/maUGM/3/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- ['find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
- [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: Thanks. This works. Now how would I achieve the hiding part of my question? I'd love to do everything in the same place.

Comment: Actually I think it *has* to be a separate function, since these divs can actually also be reordered by drag and drop (using jQuery UI Sortable). So I'd need to adjust hiding/showing the buttons also when sorting by drag and drop. (Some function I could call on sortable stop.)

Comment: Think that the edited answer should do as you require? And yeah, I ended up using a separate function for the handling of the relevant (or no-longer relevant buttons). Hope it'll be of some use to you.

Comment: Well that partially works. I don't really get the hiding part. And actually there are no buttons but links like <a>move up</a> that look like buttons. So I can't use the *disabled* parameter.

Comment: Well, I was using css's attribute selector to fade the buttons, rather than hide them completely. Still, `addClass()`/`removeClass()` could be used instead. As for not being able to use the `:disabled` selector, it would help if you could post a sample of your actual mark-up, or representative mark-up that shows what elements you *are* using.

Comment: OK. It seems I can use container.find('a.btn-move-up:first').hide(); but this only hides buttons and don't show them again when they are reordered. TIA.

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I was trying to simplify things in my question but basically my divs do contain more stuff. A table, a section, different links and those move up/down links as well. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Got it working now. I will post an answer with the markup I used.

Comment: Just edited to show one possible approach that should work properly with `a` elements. (And not much of a change, really.) =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean version of the accepted answer with a few corrections.

```
function firstAndLast(container) {

    if (!container) {

        return false;

    } else {

        container.find('a.btn-move-up, a.btn-move-down').show();
        container.find('a.btn-move-up:first').hide();
        container.find('a.btn-move-down:last').hide();
    }
}

firstAndLast($('#container'));

$('.btn-move-up, .btn-move-down').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var parent = $(this).closest('div'), grandparent = $(this).closest('#container');

    if ($(this).hasClass('btn-move-up')) {

        parent.insertBefore(parent.prev('div'));
        firstAndLast(grandparent);

    } else if ($(this).hasClass('btn-move-down')) {

        parent.insertAfter(parent.next('div'));
        firstAndLast(grandparent);
    }
});
```